# Typescript React - has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Learning typescript and trying to convert one of my other react projects to typescript to learn it.

I am getting the error on the routes in my App.tsx file - `Type '{ history: History<unknown>; location: Location<unknown>; match: match<any>; staticContext?: StaticContext | undefined; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.`

the `name` prop is also throwing a typescript error, but for now I commented it out to tackle one problem at a time. Here is my App.tsx.

```
import React from "react";
import Toaster from "./reusable/Toaster.js";
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { SocketContext, socket } from "./SocketContext";
import "./scss/style.scss";

const loading = (
  <div className="pt-3 text-center">
    <div className="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
  </div>
);
// Containers
const TheLayout = React.lazy(() => import("./containers/TheLayout"));
const Login = React.lazy(() => import("./views/auth/Login.js"));
const Logout = React.lazy(() => import("./views/auth/Logout.js"));
const Register = React.lazy(() => import("./views/auth/Register.js"));
const Activate = React.lazy(() => import("./views/auth/Activate.js"));
const ResetPass = React.lazy(() => import("./views/auth/ResetPass.js"));
const Page404 = React.lazy(() => import("./views/page404/Page404"));

const App = () => {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <Toaster />
      <React.Suspense fallback={loading}>
        <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/reset-password"
              // name="Reset Password"
              render={(props) => <ResetPass {...props} />}
            />
            <Route
              path="/logout"
              // name="Logout"
              render={(props) => <Logout {...props} />}
            />
            <Route
              path="/activate"
              // name="Activate"
              render={(props) => <Activate {...props} />}
            />
            <Route
              path="/register"
              // name="Register"
              render={(props) => <Register {...props} />}
            />
            <Route
              path="/login"
              // name="Login"
              render={(props) => <Login {...props} />}
            />
            <Route
              path="/404"
              // name="Not Found!"
              render={(props) => <Page404 {...props} />}
            />
            <Route
              path="/"
              // name="Home"
              render={(props) => <TheLayout {...props} />}
            />
          </Switch>
        </SocketContext.Provider>
      </React.Suspense>
    </HashRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What line is being flagged?

Comment: Sure - I'll update this in the question - `render={(props) => <ResetPass {...props} />}` More specifically, `ResetPass` is underlined. (and similarly down the file with `Activate`, and `Register`, `Login` ....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need import `RouteComponentProps` from `react-router-dom`

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Define custom props for your route

```
interface RouteProps {
  name: string
}
```

And use it like this on your `App` component

```
const App: React.FC<RouteComponentProps<RouteProps>> = () => {
  return (
    ...
      <Route
        path="/reset-password"
        name="Reset Password"
        render={(props) => <ResetPass {...props} />}
      />
    ...
  );
};

export default App;
```

Make sure you have `@types/react-router-dom` installed and this should fix both the name issue too.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying this now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wild guess but is react-router passing in props about the location and history to your components (via the render-props call) but they don't declare that it accepts those properties, so Typescript is telling you that the attempt to push react-router shaped props into components which don't have them will fail.